# Associated Records not saving for child model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spree, solidus

I'm working on a project that uses the Solidus engine. However, we want to modify the models, specifically by creating new models that inherit from the engine's default models.

We chose to do this rather than completely overwriting the default models or doing the decorator, feeling that the decorator was too messy but overwriting would be too hard to maintain for updates, and so tried to find a middle ground, but regardless, this is the path we chose.

The issue is that in our modified model, when it is associated with another modified model, it is not saving associated data properly via the controllers.

As an example: 
Our `Store::Product` model (inherits from `Spree::Product`) has associations set as follows:

```
has_many :variants, :class_name => "Store::Products::Variant", :allow_destroy => true
accepts_nested_attributes_for :variants, :allow_destroy => true
```

When we send in `variants_attributes` in the form data, that form data doesn't get saved, even though: 
1) if we call `@product.variants.each {|v| v.save}` in the `Store::Product` model `after_save` cb, it successfully saves all variants (indicating to me at least that there is nothing wrong with the data themselves or validations).
2) There are no errors on the associated variants' instance objects.
3) If we leave out the:

```
has_many :variants, :class_name => "Store::Products::Variant", :allow_destroy => true
accepts_nested_attributes_for :variants, :allow_destroy => true
```

(ie, just keep the default `Spree::Variant` model as the `has_many` for our `Store::Product` model), the form also works fine.

All that happens is the product's data gets saved and then it successfully redirects to wherever we set in the controller, as if nothing went wrong.

UPDATE: This is true ONLY for `update` calls (`create` works fine).

Comment: Can you post the permitted parameters in the controller ?

Comment: @shiko there's a whole bunch in this case, and some I can't post :) But the immediately relevant one is: `:variants_attributes => [:id, :sku, :cost_price, ...]`. There's some others in that array as well, for columns we added to the spree_variants table. Or was there something in particular you wanted to see?